# Pandas: Categorical sort not happening in defined order instead picks up alphabetical order

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, sorting, categorical-data

have got a dataframe `df` like below:

```
maingroup   subgroup    item    itemrank
Citrus      Mandarin    aa          12
Citrus      Lemon       bb          22
Citrus      Kiwi        cc          32
Citrus      Lemon       dd          35
Citrus      Mandarin    ee          33          
Citrus      Kiwi        ff          42
Citrus      Mandarin    gg          98
Citrus      Mandarin    hh          99
```

wanna sort the dataframe `df` with the generated list order '`grp_list`'. have tried below logic but not working as expected, instead sorting happens with alphabetical order.

**Tried logic:**

```
grp_list = df.sort_values(by=['itemrank'], ascending=True)['subgroup'].unique().tolist()    #['Mandarin', 'Lemon', 'Kiwi']
df['subgroup'] = pd.Categorical(df.subgroup, categories=grp_list, ordered=True)
```

**Errored Output:** *#this should not happen*

```
maingroup   subgroup    item    itemrank
Citrus      Kiwi        cc      32
Citrus      Kiwi        ff      42
Citrus      Lemon       dd      22
Citrus      Lemon       bb      35
Citrus      Mandarin    ee      12
Citrus      Mandarin    aa      33
Citrus      Mandarin    gg      98
Citrus      Mandarin    hh      99
```

**Expected Output:**

```
maingroup   subgroup    item    itemrank
Citrus      Mandarin    ee      12
Citrus      Mandarin    aa      33
Citrus      Mandarin    gg      98
Citrus      Mandarin    hh      99
Citrus      Lemon       dd      22
Citrus      Lemon       bb      35
Citrus      Kiwi        cc      32
Citrus      Kiwi        ff      42
```

Help me solve this! Not sure what's happening.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: add `out = df.sort_values(by=['subgroup'])`

Comment: Defining a categorical doesn't sort automatically

Answer (score 0):

Last need sorting:

```
out = df.sort_values(by=['subgroup'])
```